# checking for duplicates before saving in scriptDb

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a program that needs to store a LOT of data from a Google spreadsheet to scriptDb but the batch save keeps hanging without saving the entire batch. I'm trying to find a way to check if an object is already in the database before I add it to my array for the batch save. Of course querying the database for each object to check will exceed maximum execution time.

Is there an efficient way of querying the database once and checking each object against that query to see if it was previously stored? Then I could simply push an array of objects that were not found in the query.

Comment: Hanging? If a bulk op fails you should get a result showing the items that were not added. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb#bulk_operations

Comment: what is the query you are currently using to determine whether an object is a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidF, by "Hanging" I mean that it never completes the batch save operation, I have to cancel it manually and then checking what is in the database after cancelling reveals that some items were stored but not others but because it never completes there is n "result". This has been posted as a bug by others already.

Comment: @ScampMichael, I am using `!db.query({ID: item.ID, email: item.email, visit_date: formatVisitDate}).hasNext()`. Basically if the ID, email and visit_date are the same I don't want to duplicate it in the database.

Comment: @DavidF, Also I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885793/scriptdb-savebatch-hanging) question previously regarding the batch save problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this may seem stupid but you could always grab the data you think you would be overwriting from the db(or without the Where portion of the clause) , store it in an array, grab the data from the spreadsheet and throw it in an array and do a quick iteration through the spreadsheet array.  If the data exists in the dbarray then splice it from the spreadsheet array.  Once completed push that data up to the db.

In this way you only query the DB once, mitigate overwrites, and push as little as possible.

KT

Comment: this is what I ended up doing - must have been making the changes about the time you answered the question. Good to know I was on the right track.